# C# list count always returns 1 even when list is empty

Tags: c#, list, count

I'm trying to debug a method in C# but my basic syntax skills here seem to be lacking!  The method accepts a list of dates as a comma-separated text string.  This string is converted to a list, then processed.  However, it seems that even when an empty string is passed to the method, it still outputs 1 when the list is counted.

The code is as follows:

```
public static int DaysLeft(DateTime endDate, DateTime startDate, Boolean excludeWeekends, String excludeDates)
    {
        int counter = 0;

        List<string> excludeDatesList = new List<string>(excludeDates.Split(','));

        counter = excludeDatesList.Count;

        return counter;
    }
```

If I pass an empty string in as the excludeDates parameter, it returns 1.  If I pass a single date it returns 1.  If I pass two dates, it returns 2 etc.  So it's kind of working except where there's nothing passed in, when I'd expect it to return 0 but it actually returns 1.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even for an empty string, `Split` will return *that string* in the array, so the list will be created with... one empty string, producing a `.Count` of 1. [**Edit**: You can call `excludeDates.Split(',', StringSplitOption.RemoveEmptyEntries)` so that it doesn't.]

To make your function behave as you expect, you should probably try to parse each "date" string returned from `Split()`, and only increment the counter for valid dates.

Something like this:

```
    int counter = 0;
    var possibleDates = excludeDates.Split(',');

    foreach (var dateStr in possibleDates)
    {
        // Right now it just counts "good" dates, though could also do something
        //  with each date as well
        DateTime dt;
        if (DateTime.TryParse(dateStr, out dt))
            counter++;
    }

    return counter;
```

If you're looking for the *simplest* way, you should just check the parameter to see if it's the empty string, and return 0 in that case:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(excludeDates))
    return 0;
```

Comment: Ah, okay, thanks.  I need to process some logic only if there's a date in there, so presumably I need to use a method other than .Count to check this.  What should I use?

Comment: @Dan See the updates to my answer. The simplest is to just check for the empty string before calling split.

Comment: a `String.Empty` check would be much better

Comment: @naveen In which case? My final point is a simple parameter check. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @naveen excludeDatesList.Empty doesn't seem to be an option in intellisense.

Comment: i was mentioning about that if check before you start parsing.

Answer (score 8):

Splitting on the character is returning an empty element.

Try using `excludeDates.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the remove empty entries option.

```
var blah = "";

var split = blah.Split(new[]{';'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var split2 = blah.Split(new[]{';'});

// Returns zero
Console.WriteLine(split.Length);

// Returns one
Console.WriteLine(split2.Length);
```

Answer (score 1):

That is normal behavior. When there is nothing to split it will return a list with the string itself as the first element which counts as one.

Answer (score 1):

The array returned by String.Split() always has one element in it, even if it is the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting an empty string into the list will create a list of one element. That element would be your empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The result of calling `string.Split` on a string that doesn't contain the delimiter (in this case, a comma), is an array containing a single element, namely the original string. This also happens if the string is empty.

The solution is to specify `Split` to omit empty entries:

```
List<string> excluseDatesList = new List<string>(excludeDates.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Comment: This seems to return 0 regardless of the number of dates passed into the string.

Answer (score 0):

As dlev said.. but to add an example to illustrate, if you pass in the string 
`","`  - which is just a comma, then `",".Split(',').Count()` will return 2.
for `",,,,"`  which is just four commas, you will get back 5 for the count...

Answer (score 0):

if you look at the Split method, it has the following logic:

```
int num = this.MakeSeparatorList(separator, ref sepList);
if (num == 0 || count == 1)
{
    return new string[]
    {
        this
    };
}
```

Therefore, even if the string is an empty string it will return a single item in the array.