# C# list always shows 1 element even though the list is empty

Tags: c#, .net, string, list, count

I have a variable which stores some comma separated values as shown below

```
 string Names ="Max,Amy,Anderson"
```

I have written a code which addds each of these comma seperated values to a List as shown below

```
List<string> listOfItens= new List<string>();
listOfItens = Names.Split(',').ToList();
```

Something I have noticed is that in a scenario where `string Names =""`; is empty the listOfItens will still have a count of 1 with the value "".

Any reason why it happens like that and is there a way I can get the `listOfItens .Any() = null` or `listOfItens .count()==0`

Came across this on SO but it didnt quite answer my question [C# list count always returns 1 even when list is empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6763024/c-sharp-list-count-always-returns-1-even-when-list-is-empty)

Comment: `listOfItens = Names.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList()`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46467258/c-sharp-split-string-and-remove-empty-string

Comment: `"".Split(',')` gives `{ "" }` for the same reason than `"banana".Split(',')` gives `{ "banana" }`

Comment: *"but it didnt quite answer my question"* - Sure it did... The first paragraph on the accepted answer defines the behavior and proposes a solution.  In what way is that not what you're asking?